# How to pull data from a sheet to a UserForm in Excel VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a Excel VBA macro where a user can find an answer for their question (Kind of 'FAQ' thing) with a few clicks or by searching what they want from a UserForm.

I am new to VBA. I will try to explain my idea as clear as possible.

I have been working on this for the past 2 weeks and I'm almost there. But for some obvious reasons, an expert's advice is required to complete it.

There are 2 sheets in my Excel Workbook.

Sheet1- **"FAQ_Data4"**:

Column A: **"Reference ID"** and

Column B: **"Questions and answers"**

Each question is prefixed by **"Q"** followed by the question number (eg: Q1, Q2, Q3).

Each answer is prefixed by **"A_"** & the corresponding question's reference ID. (eg: Reference ID for **Q1**'s answer is **A_Q1**).

**Please note**: Some answers might even have one or more tables to it. So the answer reference ID might be repeated multiple times. To put it simple, if a user chooses **Q5**, I want to display all the data that is in the row with the reference ID **A_Q5**.

Sheet2- **"Home"**

There is a command button in this sheet - **"cmdHome"**.

When a user clicks the **"cmdHome"** button, it will open a UserForm (let's call it **"UserForm1"**).

**"UserForm1"** has the following:

1- **"lstQuestions"** - A List Box where all the questions are displayed.

2- **"txtSearch"** - A text box where user can type a keyword to filter the questions in the "lstQuestions" list box.

3- **"cmdClear"** - A Command Button to clear the selection / data that is in the "txtSearch" box.

4- **"cmdOk"** - A Command Button when clicked will open the second userform (let's call it "UserForm2").

**"UserForm2"** has the following:

1- **"txtQuestions"** - A Text Box that displays whatever the question is selected in "UserForm1".

2- **"txtAnswers"** - A Text Box that displays the answer to that question.

I have researched a lot and did my homework.

I was able to pull the questions from **"FAQ_Data4"**.

I made the **"txtSearch"**, **"lstQuestions"** text boxes and **"cmdClear"** command button work just fine as I wanted to.

But I am failing to pull the answers from **"FAQ_Data4"** and display it in **"UserForm2"** - **"txtAnswers"**.

I don't know where I am going wrong. I greatly appreciate if someone could help me solve this.

Below is the code that I have used in **"UserForm1"**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ' Populate the List Box with questions from FAQ_Data4

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAQ_Data4")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ws.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
        If Left(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, 1) = "Q" Then
            UserForm1.lstQuestions.AddItem cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Select all text in the txtSearch text box when userform is initialized
    Me.txtSearch.SelStart = 0
    Me.txtSearch.SelLength = Len(Me.txtSearch.Text)

    Me.BackColor = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    Me.cmdOK.BackColor = RGB(204, 255, 255)
    Me.cmdClear.BackColor = RGB(204, 255, 255)
End Sub

Private Sub lstQuestions_change()

    'Display the selected question in the text box.

    If Me.lstQuestions.ListIndex >= 0 Then
        Me.txtSearch.Value = Me.lstQuestions.List(Me.lstQuestions.ListIndex)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOk_click()
    ' Handle selection from the List Box or keyword search
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAQ_Data4")

    Dim selectedQuestion As String
    selectedQuestion = UserForm1.txtSearch.Value

    ' Check if the Search box is empty

    If Trim(UserForm1.txtSearch.Value) = "" Then

        MsgBox "No Selection made. Please select a question or enter a keyword.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Input"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    If selectedQuestion = "" Then

        ' Handle keyword search
        Dim keyword As String
        keyword = UserForm1.txtSearch.Value

        UserForm1.lstQuestions.Clear

        Dim cell As Range

        For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                UserForm1.lstQuestions.AddItem cell.Value
            End If
        Next cell
    Else
        ' Display USerForm2
        UserForm2.txtQuestions.Value = Me.txtSearch.Value
        UserForm2.Show
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_Enter()

    ' Select all text in the Search Box when it is clicked

    Me.txtSearch.SelStart = 0
    Me.txtSearch.SelLength = Len(Me.txtSearch.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    
    ' Filter question based on keyword
    Dim keyword As String
    keyword = Trim(Me.txtSearch.Value) ' Remove leading and trailing spaces
    
    ' clear the list Box
    Me.lstQuestions.Clear

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAQ_Data4")
    
    Dim cell As Range

    If keyword = "" Then
        ' If the search box is empty, show all questions
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Left(cell.Value, 1) = "Q" Then ' Filter for reference ID
                Me.lstQuestions.AddItem ws.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value
            End If
        Next cell
    Else
        ' Filter question based on the keyword
        For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Left(cell.Value, 1) = "Q" Then ' Filter for reference ID
                If InStr(1, ws.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    Me.lstQuestions.AddItem ws.Cells(cell.Row, 2).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

    ' Clear the text in the search text box
    UserForm1.txtSearch.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Now I want to display a range of contents.

The contents are in sheet "FAQ_Data4".

I want the contents to be displayed in "UserForm2" - "txtAnswers" text box.

Consider the below steps to be followed when "Userform2" is opened:

1- See what is the text in "Userform2" - "txtQuestion" text box.

2- In column B in sheet "FAQ_Data4", check in which row number there is an exact match for that text.

3- After finding the row number, go to column A in same row.

4- Check what is the reference ID in that row (make sure that it starts with "Q").

5- Prefix "A_" to the reference ID that you found. Now let's call this as "answerRefID".

6- In column A, find the range of cells that has the "answerRefID".

7- Select the complete rows.

8- In "Userform2" - "txtAnswers" text box, display the entire contents that are selected.

I tried the below code. Nothing is getting displayed in the txtAnswers text box.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Step 1: Get the text from "txtQuestion" text box
    Dim searchText As String
    searchText = Me.txtQuestion.Value

    ' Step 2: Find the row number with an exact match in column B
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FAQ_Data4")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim matchRow As Long
    matchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(searchText, ws.Range("B1:B" & lastRow), 0)

    ' Step 3: Get the reference ID from column A in the matched row
    Dim referenceID As String
    referenceID = ws.Cells(matchRow, 1).Value

    ' Step 4: Ensure the reference ID starts with "Q"
    If Left(referenceID, 1) = "Q" Then
        ' Step 5: Prefix "A_" to the reference ID
        Dim answerRefID As String
        answerRefID = "A_" & referenceID

        ' Step 6: Find the range of cells that have the "answerRefID"
        Dim answerRange As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set answerRange = ws.Range("A:A").Find(answerRefID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not answerRange Is Nothing Then
            ' Step 7: Select the complete rows
            ws.Rows(answerRange.Row & ":" & answerRange.Row).Select

            ' Step 8: Display the entire contents in "txtAnswers" text box
            Me.txtAnswers.Value = Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Cells(answerRange.Row, 1).Resize(1, ws.Columns.Count).Value), vbCrLf)
        Else
            MsgBox "Answer not found for the given question."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Reference ID does not start with 'Q'."
    End If
End Sub
```

Kindly help

Comment: Help me understand where you're stuck, showing the results of all relevant answers to the question selected in the List-Box? Are you showing the answers in "User-Form1" or "User-Form2"? Are you trying to show multiple answers in column B that match a "Q" in column A"?

Comment: @ShaiRado 1- Yes, I am stuck at the point where I am unable to show all the relevant answers to the question selected in the List-Box. 2- I want to show the answers in "txtAnswers" in "UserForm2". 3- Lets take an example. Cell A7 = Q7 (which is the reference ID and it is the 7th question). Let's assume that there is a two line answer to this question along with a sample table (cells B8 to H15). The reference ID for the answer is A_Q7. So Cell A8 to A15 will be having the value A_Q7. I hope I have explained it well. Please let me know.

Comment: But you want to show only the data in column B, cells "B8:B15", you want to show multiple rows in a single text-box? Any reason why not use a List-Box?

Comment: I want to show multiple rows and multiple columns, because as I said, the answers sometimes might even have tables. It doesn't matter if it is a text or list box. I just want to solve the problem.